# How can I check if an element is visible using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am using the Protractor software for my end to end tests. Some elements are being set with ng-show.

Can someone tell me how I can check if these elements are visible or not with Protractor ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that your element has the ID "foo", you could do, for example

```
expect($('#foo').isDisplayed()).toBe(true); // or false to test that it's hidden
```

or

```
expect(element(by.id('foo')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: If it is false, how can we turn element visibility to true?

Comment: protractor is a web browser. You would do, programmatically, what an end user would do with his browser to make is visible.

Comment: The problem, the button is visible but the click isn't performed here is my problem, i'm using Appium with protractor and i've recently considered that in inspector visible = false,  i have a doubt if this is the problem origin or not ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871071/click-function-isnt-working-in-protractor-scripts

Answer (score 2):

I've found that isDisplayed() returns a promise, and in the .then, you are passed the boolean. So looks more like this:

```
$('#foo').isDisplayed().then(function(isDisplaying) {
    expect(isDisplaying).toBe(true);
  });
```

Comment: That's true but in this case, expect will automatically resolve the promise and only then do the actual assertion, so there is no need to use `then()` here.

Comment: ah so it with expect its implied? So what would I expect for in that case? What would it look like? I won't have a handle on the boolean passed back from the `.then`.

Comment: This works for me, however I couldn't use .toBe(true/false) on expect, it said it wasn't a property, expect(!isDisplaying) worked though.

Answer (score 1):

expect knows to deal with promise so the following works.

```
expect($('#foo').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have many elements by the same id/class and you want to `assert` on the count of number of visible elements

```
var elements = element.all(by.id('foo'))
               .filter(function(el){
                    return el.isDisplayed();
                });

expect(elements.count()).toEqual(2);
```